# Getting an element from an array of an array in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

using Angular - I have a json file with an array `people[]`, which has an array `phones[]`

I want to return

`people[index].phones[index].phonenumber`

```
(where people.personid = x and people.phones.phoneid = y)
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: Can the `peopleId` and `phoneId` be used as `indieces` of the people array and phones array respectively? Or are both these arrays array of objects?

Comment: Are you looking to get every single phone number all of the people? Or, are you looking at getting a list of phone numbers for each person? Or, are you wanting to get a list of phone numbers for a specific person (I think this is what @SiddAjmera was looking for with his question)?

Comment: phones[] is an array of phone numbers - so I am looking for a specific phone number of a type phonetypeID. 

i.e., when phonetypeID = 1, the associated phonenumber is the office number. 

Every person has several phone numbers. So, to create a list of office numbers for each person I need 

per personID, phonenumber where phonetypeID = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `filter` function on the arrays.

```
let person = people.filter(person => person.personId === x);
let phone = person && person.phones.filter(phone => phone.phoneId === y);
```

---

Here's a **[Working Example as a Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-find-with-person-id-and-phone-id?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your ref.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex.  Why not just access the index of the array directly?

Comment: Can you please read the question again? index has nothing to do with the fields the user has in there. OP wants to get the person and phone based on `personId` and `phoneId` which could be different from the indices of the Objects in the respective arrays.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter function which returns a filtered array

```js
private filterPhone(x:number,y:number) : number { 
    let phoneNum : number;
    let person = this.people.filter(person => person.personId === x);
    let phone = person.length > 0 && person[0].phones.filter(phone => phone.phoneId === y);
    if(phone.length > 0 && phone[0].phoneNumber){
      phoneNum = phone[0].phoneNumber;
    }
    return phoneNum;
}
```

Or you could use a findIndex() function for achieving this.

```js
private findPhoneById(x:any,y:any) : number { 
    let result : number = -1; 
    let personIndx = this.people.findIndex(p => p.personId === x);
    if(personIndx > result){
        let phoneIndx = this.people[personIndx].phones.findIndex(phone => phone.phoneId === y);
        if(phoneIndx > result){
          result = this.people[personIndx].phones[phoneIndx].phoneNumber;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```